# linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : R^4 → R^2$ be the linear transformation given by

$$T(x_1; x_2; x_3; x_4) = (2x_1 + 2x_2 + 4x_3 + 6x_4; x_1 + 2x_2 + 2x_3 + 4x_4):$$

i. Find a basis for nullspace(T) and hence:

$\hspace{0.1in}$A. Find nullity(T).

$\hspace{0.1in}$B. Find nullspace(T), that is, describe it explicitly.

ii. Find a basis for range(T) and hence:

$\hspace{0.1in}$A. Find rank(T).

$\hspace{0.1in}$B. Find range(T), that is, describe it explicitly.

Comment: Any thoughts on the issue? Most new posters find [how to ask](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to be useful. This would be a decent post if you added some perspective on your thoughts and attempts. In fact, it would probably get many responses with that addition. Just click edit and add your thoughts and attempts below the question as a new paragraph.

Comment: $N(T)=\{X\in R^4:T(X)=0\}$. So, (2x1+2x2+4x3+6x4;x1+2x2+2x3+4x4) = 0. Solving this linear equation, you can use row reduce echelon method. 

There are the theorem that Null+Rank= dimension of Domain

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to give you a hint as to the methods via a different example.

If I had a similar system such as 
$$(x,y)\mapsto(2x+y,4x+2y),$$
I can write as a matrix: 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2&1\\4&2
\end{pmatrix},$$
which in rref becomes: 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\0&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
This tells us the null space, that is, the solution set to the equation $Ax=0$, is 
$$x=0, y=t, $$
that is, $y$ is a free variable (null space is the $x$-axis). In other words, a basis for the null space is 
$$\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}.$$

The rref also tells us a way to represent the range, that is, by observing the pivot columns of the rref, we select those columns from the original matrix to describe the range. In this case a basis for the range, or column space, is 
$$\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\4
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}.$$

(Why does it work this way? That is, why does rref tell us the null space, and it's pivot columns tell us a basis for the range? Here's how I like to think of it: the row operations can be thought of as matrix multiplication of $Ax$ by an elementary matrix on the left, that is, $E_1Ax$, and this continues, $E_2E_1Ax$, etc. Each one is invertible, so a vector is a solution to $Ax=0$ if and only if it's a solution to the rref. So the null space of $A$ is equal to the null space of the rref. This doesn't quite hold for the range, since we are in a sense continually acting on the codomain. However, any linear relations that hold in the matrix $A$ are preserved by the invertible row operations, so linear dependence and independence is preserved. Thus, since the pivot columns form a basis for the (Edit: *range of*) rref, so do the corresponding columns of the original matrix $A$ (Edit: *form a basis for the range of $A$*).)